# Delayed jobs restarting + Capistrano best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, delayed-job

I just wanted to understand best practices for restarting delayed jobs workers using capistrano. I've got a bunch of workers that process long jobs (up to 10minutes).

I've come across two scenarios during a deploy while the workers are processing-

1)

I stop delayed jobs workers before deploy: restart task and start them again after the deploy:restart task.

But in this scenario, it won't restart my app until the delayed jobs are finished (this may be ok - but the cap deploy script literally sits there until the job is done and it can stop all workers) before proceeding with the app restart task.

2) 
I also tried stopping/starting the delayedjobs workers after the restart task - but this caused all sorts of dramas whereby the tasks would be halted without waiting yet the delayedjobs table had them listed and assigned to a worker with a PID that doesn't exist!

Any other options? Or am I forced to wait as mentioned in scenario 1.

Many thanks.

**Edit:** I just realised with scenario 1 .. it doesn't wait! The stop task will forcefully kill my worker even though it hasn't finished!

```
 ** [out] delayed_job: trying to stop process with pid 9630...
 ** [out] delayed_job: process with pid 9630 won't stop, we forcefully kill it...
 ** [out] 
 ** [out] delayed_job: process with pid 9630 successfully stopped.
```

Answer (score 1):

If your deploy changes change the database schema, then you're forced to wait.

If it doesn't, you can set a flag that the workers check at the end of every job. Upon deploy, you set the flag, and once a long-running worker finishes, it replaces itself by exec-ing a new worker. That way you're never really starting and stopping workers - they're just always running, and will load the latest code on starting the next job.

Answer (score 1):

Actually not sure that my solution is good enough. But anyway it have a chance to live. Just create a Rake task and start it on the deployment process:

```
  desc 'Wait for delayed job completion'
  task wait_for_complete_background_jobs: :environment do
    loop do
      exit unless Delayed::Job.where(locked_at: nil).exists?
      sleep 2
    end
  end
```

The rake task is waiting for locked jobs and exits right after the locked tasks list is empty. This is how I imagine its usage (note, the sequence of the operations is important):

1. Stop web server
2. Start the rake task
3. Stop delayed job
4. Update code
5. Start delayed job
6. Start web server

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the second scenario to put your pid file in a shared directory to avoid it disapear. The second scenario can work and if you don't have some migration to can be in conflict with your delayed job.

Comment: Yep they already are. In /shared/pids/ just like all other shared files (images & logs etc).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving my "long running processes" to a custom Ruby script using the daemons gem. Thanks for the advice though guys!

Answer (score 0):

Good question - I've tried a lot of different things, but my strategy is to keep things simple.

1. Don't use God or Monit or anything that runs as root, requiring the same user that runs your app to have sudo privileges to restart it. Given recent events in rails security, the last thing you want is your app user having a good possibility of getting root.
2. Instead, use a `rake` or `thor` task to start/stop/restart tasks.
3. Use `nohup` to daemonize the process.

Here are some very basic thor tasks that can manage simple background tasks with `resque`, for example:

```
class Resque < Thor

  desc "start", "Starts resque workers"
  def start
    system('(PIDFILE=/tmp/resque-myapp.pid nohup rake resque:work QUEUES="*" &) &')
  end

  desc "stop", "Stops resque workers"
  def stop
    pidfile = '/tmp/resque-myapp.pid'
    if File.exist?(pidfile)
      pid = File.open(pidfile).first.to_i
      puts "Killing process #{pid}..."
      system("kill -QUIT #{pid}")
      File.delete(pidfile)
      sleep(5)
    else
      puts "No resque pidfile found"
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your `deploy.rb` file:

```
after 'deploy',         "resque:restart"

namespace :resque do
  task :restart do
    puts "Stopping resque workers.."
    run("cd #{current_path} && thor resque:stop", :options => { :pty => true })
    puts "Starting resque workers.."
    run("cd #{current_path} && thor resque:start > /dev/null 2>&1 &", :options => { :pty => true })
  end
end
```

This strategy can even work with RVM, if that's of interest. You will need something like this before the restart command, in addition to the usual `rvm-capistrano` tasks:

```
after  'deploy:setup', 'thor:install'
namespace :thor do
  task :install do
    puts "Installing thor..."
    run_locally('cap rvm:install_gem GEM=thor')
  end
end

after "deploy",         "rvm:trust_rvmrc"
namespace :rvm do
  task :trust_rvmrc do
    run "rvm rvmrc trust #{release_path}"
  end
end
```

And last but not least, with RVM it's best to put into `~/.bashrc` what the installer normally splits between that file and `.bash_profile`, and make sure the mode of the file is 0400 so it won't get clobbered by the RVM install program:

```
PATH=$HOME/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin/:$PATH # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export PATH
export RAILS_ENV=production
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: I disagree with not using monit. Monit starts workers as deploy user and deploy user only has sudo access to monit command.

Comment: But aren't the monit config files found in the app config itself, writable by the deploy user in `config/recipes/templates/monit/*`? People always refer to the "deploy user" but in fact it's the "app-runs-as user". So if you give sudo access to monit, and monit's configurations are, in effect, world writable if your app is hacked... Sorry, I just don't see this as a secure solution.

Comment: My point is, if you give any sudo privileges to the app-runs-as user, you're also giving them to any potential hacker from a web browser. Even if you limit that access to one program, I've never seen any security protocol which would recommend giving attackers the ability to run anything as root.

Comment: +1 I understand your concern for not giving access to root, but keep my templates in `/etc/monit/conf/*`. And I didn't notice that monit configs are world writable.

Comment: I would like to change my vote but SO has locked it till answer is edited.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend you check out [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) - probably best gem for managing delayed jobs. I tried different solutions starting with old-forgotten cron+wget, but whenever gives best control over this. And it integrates great with Capistrano. HTH